# Grab an URL after a submit_form

Tags: rvest

I want to scrape the database of 'Peoples Daily', a Chinese newspaper. One way to get access to an archive from '47 - today is by the DFN (Deutsches Forschungsnetzwerk) and an valid crossasia.org account.

1.The first step is to choose your institution at https://login.erf.sbb.spk-berlin.de/hanshibboleth/login, which redirects you to the DFN webpage with a formular to select your institution.

2. Choose Crossasia.org (VHO)

This will redirect you to the login-page of crossasia.org

My problem is now the following : 
I think I achieve the first step with the `rvest` package running the following code

```
require("rvest")
session <- html_session("https://login.erf.sbb.spk-berlin.de/hanshibboleth/login")

form <- html_form(session)[[1]]

form <- set_values(form,
                   user_idp = "CrossAsia.org (VHO)")
```

If you repeat the first step in your browser the webpage redirects you immediately to CrossAsia.org, sadly it seems that this does not work in R. So here is my question :

How can I jump to the login-page or grab the URL of the login-page? Since the login-page seems to have session-specific token aswell, copy-paste the login-page link from your browser is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after playing around with the chrome dev-tool I found that using 
https://sp.erf.sbb.spk-berlin.de/Shibboleth.sso/Login?SAMLDS=1&target=ss%3Amem%3A34f673898b5d4cb8f67f552c14c99ae1ed8d8e9185419b104896382fd711f1a2?user_idp=CrossAsia.org%20(VHO)&entityID=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.crossasia.org%2Fidp%2Fshibboleth directs you automatically to the login page. So case closed.

To give a more general answer : 
Before I clicked on "Select" button of the page, I opened the 'network' tab of the dev-tool. Therefore just press Command+Option+C (Mac) or Control+Shift+C (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS). Then check the box "Preserve Log" so all interactions between sending the request and redirecting is logged. Afterwards just check the called links and try them in another browser (or delete your cache) to prevent that the result is just a cached version of the target webpage.